# Jquery - animations working fine in all browsers except IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, cross-browser, doctype

I have made a site that uses a good deal of Jquery animations and plugins. It works fine on all browsers except for IE where only some of the jquery works.

If anyone wants to look the site is: http://host.pixelframe.net.au/~pptestco/

What is meant to occur is several sub-menus are meant to appear when the large menu items are clicked (Products, Manufacturing, etc). This occurs on some pages: http://host.pixelframe.net.au/~pptestco/index.php?id=8 but not on the home page.

The error seams to be linked to slidUp()/slidDown() animations.

So far, I have only tested on IE 9.

Looking in IEs console it says it has found errors in the jquery.minl.js file I have linked to  from Google librarys (version 1.8.2)

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
```

It also says it has issues with my DOCTYPE though I have tried both transitional and strict.

Here are the errors:

```
SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object 
~pptestco, line 1 character 1

SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 66373
```

Can anyone suggest a way to resolve this?

EDIT: Update - I have no idea whats is happening. A different result seems to occur each time I load IE...

Comment: Lead us a bit more.  Where are the animations?  What page(s) give the error?  What animation(s) do you think the error is related to?  Just unleashing us on your website and saying "fix it" is a bit much to ask.

Comment: Consider adding version(s) of IE you have problem with and try non-minimized version of JQuery to get better error information. Also you don't need thankyou notes...

Comment: @EliGassert Sorry - didnt mean to come accross as that. I will add more to the question above to clarifye

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have tryed the non-minimzed version. It seems to have an issue with the append function, which makes sense in my UI

Comment: "_______ works fine in every browser, except IE" -- Welcome to web development, son. The antacids are over there.